# attach multiple file types(pdf, xlsx) from Gdrive to email using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out a way to attach multiple types of files(pdf, xlsx) from drive to my emails using appscript. I have the below code which attaches .xlsx file type to emails based on the name of the file in a specific Gdrive folder.

So, i have a spreadsheet which has the following headers:

name, email address, header3, header4, status, filename

So basically i did a for loop to go through each line and attach the file mentioned in header: filename, to the email and it registers the header: status as "Email Sent". 
I understand the logic behind, but not sure what or how to code in to make sure it picks up even if the file type is pdf, word, etc for different rows in the spreadsheet. I also am guessing that something needs to be done in

> var email = GmailApp.sendEm.............................spreadsheetml.sheet")]});

the code:

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Info");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var email_Sent = "EMAIL SENT" // This constant is written in column 5 for rows for which an email has been sent successfully.
  var dailyQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var replyTo = ss.getRange(1, 10).getValue();

   if((lr-1) > dailyQuota) {
   Browser.msgBox("Your daily quota is " + dailyQuota + " emails and you are trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails." + " Hence the emails were not sent!!"); 
  } else {
    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++) {

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var productPurchase = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var dueDate = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); 
      var emailSent = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue(); //fetch if email has been sent or not
      var fileName = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); //fetch file name from column 6 from spreadsheet
      var fileFromDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById("1oa2Yw3A7n4vbTKAgQVEfNjVxgBi0MaP8").getFilesByName(fileName); //fetch from drive by file name

      if (emailSent != "EMAIL SENT") {
      var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue(); //fetch template from sheet
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{product}",productPurchase).replace("{date}",dueDate); //body of the message, replace with var in sheet "template" 
      var email = GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, "Reminder: Payment due on " + productPurchase + " purchase", messageBody, {from: alias[0], replyTo: replyTo, 
                                     attachments: [fileFromDrive.next().getAs("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")]}); //send email with attachment

      var cellUpdate = ss.getRange(i, 6).setValue(email_Sent); //to update column 5 once email sent 

        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //to flush out pending actions on spreadsheet

      } //close for if statement
      Logger.log(cellUpdate);

    } //close for loop statement

  } //close else statement
  Logger.log(dailyQuota); 
}
```